# CanCan on polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I have a polymorphic model, TimeReport. You can have either internal TimeReport's, or TimeReports associated with a project. However, if you have a TimeReport associated with a project, you can only associate it with a project to which you belong.

So, how would I CanCan this? I can't really do

```
can :create, TimeReport, project_id: user.project_ids
```

as I would have wanted from the beginning.. Any tips? (I could of course do this in the model validation rules, but I'd rather not, unless there's a good reason to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to provide more information to get a good answer... You say a time_report is associated with a project so that means `time_report.project` exists?

In your controller:

```
  @time_report = TimeReport.new # or whatever
  authorize! :create, @time_report
```

In Ability:

```
  can [ :create ], TimeReport do |time_report|
    user.project_ids.include? time_report.project_id 
  end
```

Notice the following:

- you probably cannot use load_and_authorize_resource, but maybe you can. I tend not to use it, but if @time_report is exactly the one you need, then it will work out.
- the variable `time_report` that gets passed inside `can()` in your Ability is the one and the same with `@time_report` in your controller. That's kind of what makes CanCan beautiful ; )

Comment: Didn't know you could execute a block in CanCan like that! Great stuff!